# Heroku Create Unknown Protocol SSL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, heroku

I'm new to Ruby and have created a site in Rails, I'm trying to run heroku create on my Windows machine and after generating a public key through git gui, I'm getting this error

Uploading ssh public key C:\Users\me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:590:in `connect': unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:590:in`connect'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:557:in `do_start'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:546:in`start'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:150:in `transmit
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:55:in`execute'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:30:in `execute'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.4.2/lib/restclient/resource.rb:63:in`post'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.9.9/lib/heroku/client.rb:464:in `send'
         ... 17 levels...
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.9.9/lib/heroku/command.rb:20:in`run'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-1.9.9/bin/heroku:13
        from c:/ruby/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from c:/ruby/bin/heroku:19

Is there something I need to set up for SSL?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try reinstalling Ruby using something like http://rubyinstaller.org/